If $E^{\circ} \neq \emptyset$ then $\overline E= \overline{E^\circ}$(closure of $E^\circ$)
I have some trouble in understanding this proof:
Let X be a normed space. Let E be a convex subset of X. If $E^{\circ} \neq \emptyset$ then $\overline E= \overline{E^\circ} $(closure of $E^\circ$).
Proof: Clearly $\overline{E^\circ} \subset \overline E .$ We are trying to show $E \subset \overline{E^\circ}$. Consider $a \in E^\circ$. Let $r > 0$ be such that $U(a,r) \subset E$ , that is, $a + ry \in E$ for every $y \in X $ with $||y|| < 1.$ Let $x \in E$ and $x_t = ta + (1-t)x$. We claim that $U(x_t, tr) \subset E$, that is, $x_t + try \in E$ for every $y \in X$ with $||y|| < 1$. This is obvious from the convexity of $E$, because $x_t + try = t(a + ry) + (1-t)x$, where $a + ry \in E$ and $x \in E$. Thus $x_t \in E^\circ$. Since $x_t \rightarrow x$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, we have $x \in \overline{E^\circ}$.
I am stuck at understanding the last part. I thought that they are using the fact, "If $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ then there is a sequence $x_n$ in $A$ such that it converges to $x$." But how $x_t$ can be a sequence? Please give some idea on it!

Shiv-ani, you should write in your post your ideas about your problem. This is not a “do-my-work” website.

Just take $t = {1 \over n}$ to get a sequence.

Theorem 6.1 in Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis" has a delightful proof of this fact.

With for instance $t=1/n$ you get a sequence $x'_n:=x_{1/n}$ that is convergent to $x$. In fact for any convergent to zero sequence $(t_n)$ with $0<t_n<1$ and null limit you have that $x_{t_n}$ belongs to $\stackrel{\circ}{E}$ and $x_{t_n}\rightarrow x$ as $n$ goes to infinity.
